# Date format in an Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, html.dropdownlistfor

New to MVC, bear with me.

I'm trying to populate an `Html.DropDownListFor` control with a list of dates.  I need the text to be just `MM/DD/YYYY` and the data to be `DateTime`.  I can't figure out how to format the text to drop the date.

Here's the code from the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RunDate, Model.ReportRunDates, "--Select Report Date--", new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

From the viewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ReportRunDates { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public string RunDate { get; set; }
```

from the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StatusReport()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModels.ReportHistoryViewModel
        {
            ReportRunDates = GetReportRunDates(),
        };
        return View("StatusReportSearch", vm);
    }

private SelectList GetReportRunDates()
{
    var ReportRunDates = new List<ReportHistory>();

    ReportRunDates = RenewalUnderwritingLayer.GetReportRunDates();

    return new SelectList(ReportRunDates, "RunDate", "RunDate");
}
```

Code from the model:

```
public class ReportHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ReportHistoryGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunDate { get; set; }
}
```

Code that calls out to DAL:

```
    public static List<ReportHistory> GetReportRunDates()
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkSQL())
        {
            return uow.Repository<ReportHistory>()
                .Query()
                .Get()
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I've got the control displaying data, which felt like a huge win in and of itself, but I cannot figure out how to drop the timestamp in the text display of the drop down.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see you using your SelectList method anywhere.  that collection needs to be supplied to the dropdownlist helper instead of Model.ReportRunDates...

Comment: Sorry, edited that out.  Was trying something else and forgot to delete it before posting.

Comment: **GetRenewalHistoryReportRunDates** can't return **ReportRunDates** which is **List<ReportHistory>()**. What does ReportHistory look like? You are not showing us all.

Comment: `GetRenewalHistoryReportRunDates` doesn't return anything. You should get a compile error for that. Anyway, using drop-down list for `DateTime` is not a good idea. Try to use a jQuery DatePicker instead.

Comment: Sorry, added the report history model.

I agree, drop down list is terrible for this but it wasn't up to me.  Basically I'm pulling a list of dates the report was actually run and then loading the dropDownList so they can select from it.

Comment: your code examples dont help much but you can just format the dates before you put them in the selectlist.. here's an example https://dotnetfiddle.net/X5w5VQ

Comment: Sorry about the code examples, I tried to change some of the names to be anonymous and probably made it harder than it needed to be.  

I see where you're going with it, can't believe how much harder I made it on myself, but on this line:


    ReportRunDates = dates.Select(a => new SelectListItem { Text =     a.ToString("d"), Value = a.ToString("d") })

|
the toString functions are returning "no overload for tostring takes 1 argument"

Comment: If you need help, you'll have to update your code.

Comment: Jamie, thanks for the help.  I'll be better about putting the code up in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the date when generating the `SelectListItem`. Change your `GetReportRunDates()` method to

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetReportRunDates()
{
  return RenewalUnderwritingLayer.GetReportRunDates().Select(r => new SelectListItem
  {
    Text = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", r.RunDate),
    Value = r.RunDate
  };
}
```

Note if you also want to post pack just the date component (with the time equal to 00:00:00), then you can also format the `Value` property in the same way.